# Allowed usages of memset in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm trying to figure out when the standard allows using `memset`.

cppreference [claims](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) that `memset` can be used with trivially copyable types (modulo potentially overlapping subobjects — let's disregard those). The closest I could find while reading the standard (in particular, the C++17 draft publically available) is about `memcpy` — indeed, there is a clause that explicitly allows copying the representation of a trivially copyable object into a char array and back, but that's about it.

In fact, looks like the standard doesn't even define the semantics of `memset` with respect to the C++ entities it defines.

So, objects of which types am I allowed to `memset`, what are the restrictions on the value I'm allowed to `memset` them to and how to prove this?

Comment: Linked duplicate does not have the `language-lawyer` tag, but has answers that talk about what the standard strictly allows.

Comment: I’m not a lawyer, but it seems that `memset`ting an object should be valid as long as 1) the type is trivially copyable, and 2) the call results in a valid representation for that object.

Comment: @walnut thanks, the accepted answer there exactly answers my question.